# Overriding celery result table (celery_taskmeta) for Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, celery

I am using celery to do some distributed tasks and want to override `celery_taskmeta` and add some more columns. I use Postgres as DB and SQLAlchemy as ORM. I looked up celery docs but could not find out how to do it.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You could just extend `celery_taskmeta` via database (normal `ALTER...` SQL) or sqlalchemy migrations like `alembic`.

Comment: Yes, I want to extend the table to include few more columns and want celery to dump results into my customized table and not `celery_taskmeta`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different approach - add an extra table with your extended data. This table would have a foreign-key constraint that would ensure each record is related to the particular entry in the `celery_taskmeta`. Why this approach? - It separates your domain (domain of your application), from the Celery domain. Also it does not involve modifying the table structure that may (in theory it should not) cause trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Following the documentation:

> database_table_names Default: {} (empty mapping).
>
> When SQLAlchemy is configured as the result backend, Celery
>   automatically creates two tables to store result meta-data for tasks.
>   This setting allows you to customize the table names:
>
> use custom table names for the database result backend.

```
database_table_names = {
     'task': 'myapp_taskmeta',
     'group': 'myapp_groupmeta'
 }
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-table-names